# Research CALL (Computer-Assisted Language Learning) with mobile devices

Tags: mobile, user-research, research, user-centered-design

I am looking for more **researches** on this particular use of technology.
If anyone know similar cases or studies about, please, share with me!

In the meantime, thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific on what you want the research for?

[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=computer%20assisted%20language%20learning&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj524XD2dTLAhUK0xoKHUpzDyIQgQMIGzAA&safe=active) has a whole list of research related to CALL, and there is a Wikipedia page for [Mobile-Assisted Language Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile-assisted_language_learning)

For first hand research, I would look into [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/), [Babbel](http://www.babbel.com/), or [Busuu](https://www.busuu.com/enc/) which are a very successful example of MALL.